# How does one repeat a 'shake' CSS class based upon React state (so not onClick)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animations

I was trying to apply a shake to a number upon addition using react state as well as CSS keyframe class based animation.

I successfully made the number shake upon addition, in this case, once a number is added the count shakes, but after the first addition the count is not applied.|

For some clarity here's the code for the counter wrapped with 'shake' that is activated via CSS class

```
  if (isCurrentUser) {
          setComboCountClass('comboShake')
          setMsgCount(count => {
            return { ...count, [userId]: count[userId] ? count[userId] + 1 : 1 };
          });
          setComboCountClass('comboShakeEnd')
        }
```

The counted number shakes once upon addition-- but not again after first addition? I would love help on this, by the way, this is my first question using StackOverflow so feel free to tell me anything I can do better

Comment: After `.comboShakeEnd` added and do the shake thing, you need to remove it.